# Can't pass bcrypted value to a laravel blade vue

Tags: laravel, laravel-vue

I'm trying to pass a bcrypt value from my controller to my model and then to my view, the bcrypt is : `$2y$10$jTlSwN9nLTGSoaljl2ZIJu8wsbY2StYUJGjWz.7LUx6K20ATLj/m2`,

as I passed it into my laravel blade's vue inline-template as a props, it gives me error saying:

**[Vue warn]: Error compiling template: invalid expression: Invalid or unexpected token in $2y$10$jTlSwN9nLTGSoaljl2ZIJu8wsbY2StYUJGjWz.7LUx6K20ATLj/m2 Raw expression: :access_code="$2y$10$jTlSwN9nLTGSoaljl2ZIJu8wsbY2StYUJGjWz.7LUx6K20ATLj/m2".**

**My Controller:**

```
$user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();

$encrypted_access_code = bcrypt($user->id . ' ' . uniqid() . ' ' . now());

return CallbackRedirects::callbackredirects($encrypted_access_code);
```

**My Model**

```
public static function callbackredirects($access_code) {
    return view('callback.callback-redirect')->with('access_code', $access_code);
}
```

**My View**

```
@extends('layout.layout-main')
@section('content')
<callbackredirect inline-template :access_code="{{ $access_code }}">
<div>
    {{ $access_code }}
</div>
</callbackredirect>
@endsection
```

But when I pass any string, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for the colon `:` before access_code, since it's not JavaScript code you are passing. Use: `access_code="{{ $access_code }}"`.

It's better to use `access-code="{{ $access_code }}"`, which is a html compliant property, accessible as `accessCode` in vue.